# Facebook Login UI issue into WebView

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview

I want to load my url into the webview then when i am trying to login using facebook then the redirect page coming with an issue.Here is my code:

```
 WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://***");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }


        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            try
            {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //For Android 4.1 only
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
        {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

And here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LoadingText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Please wait, Loading.."
    android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Below is my Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRfH8.png)

Comment: setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority priority)
This method was deprecated in API level 18. It is not recommended to adjust thread priorities, and this will not be supported in future versions.

Comment: @charuka okay.What will be my solution to solve my issue?did u see the screenshot?

Comment: share your xml code.

Comment: I got my solution by comment out the code "mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");"

Answer (score 0):

don't use deprecated methods ,do it like this and it should work

```
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

Comment: i did not load "https://www.facebook.com/".I am tring to load my website from this facebook login page will call.

Comment: whatever your problem was that view is not fully loaded as wanted and its addressed here try it in this way. Don't wait till everything is done for you. go and find out the difference and try to make use of it